# Flutter FAILURE: Build failed with an exception Keystore file not set

Tags: flutter, dart, apk, android-app-bundle

i just signed my app and created a key. Now when I run flutter build apk or flutter build appbundle then I run into this failure:

```
FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.
* What went wrong:
Execution failed for task ':app:validateSigningRelease'.
> Keystore file not set for signing config release
> Keystore file not set for signing config release
```

What can I do to avoid this?

Answer (score 0):

To sign your App after creating a key you have to reference the key in a keys.properties file. You also after to add some reference at the build.gradle file located at [project_dir]/android/app/. Try following the steps described in this article from flutter.dev; https://flutter.dev/docs/deployment/android duly and  you should be able to build a release for your app afterwards.

Comment: Can you enter what you have in your console when you run the build command using with `-v` or  `--verbose`?